# How to use inheritance in protobuf

Tags: c++, json, protocol-buffers

Currently I'm using json to pass messages between 2 different languages (C++ and Dart) but I quickly realized json isn't perfect for this. I'm looking into protobuf.

I just finished reading https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3 but I couldn't find anything that matches my use case: inheritance.

For example, I want to serialize an instance of `Profile`:

```
class Profile{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<VPN>> vpns;
}

class VPN {
//...
}

class OpenVPN: public VPN {
//...
}

class WireguardVPN: public VPN {
//...
}

class CiscoVPN: public VPN {
//...
}
```

But `profile.vpns` can hold all types of VPNs: `OpenVPN`, `WireguardVPN`, `CiscoVPN`. How can I translate this behavior to protobuf?

This is how I was doing in json:

```
class VPN {
    enum Type {
    OPENVPN,WIREGUARDVPN, CISCOVPN
    };
    Type type;
}
```

then when parsing the json, I first looked into the type field, and according to it, I called the json parser for each child.

However protobuf generates the parsers automatically on the 2 languages (which is great). So I'd like to know how this can be made automatically

Comment: It's a while ago when I was working with Google PB, but IIRC the closest match they have for _inheritance_ are _message extensions_. You can deal with these in  a hierarchical class model, but you'll need to wrap the generated code, rather then directly inherit from it.

Comment: Protobufs tend to model inheritance via containment in a `oneof`, e.g. `message VPN { int64 some_common_field = 1; oneof derived { OpenVPN open_vpn = 2; WireguardVPN wireguard_vpn = 3; CiscoVPN cisco_vpn = 4;} }`